# Faster way to execute multiple methods in different package simultaneously

Tags: python, performance, concurrency

I have created `.py` and `packages` contains `methods`...

So I need to `execute` all those methods in a faster way...

I have imagine that I create an `app.py` as the below one and call all methods I need:

```
from txt_to_csv import  convert_to_csv
from inspect import ismethod
from meta_data import all_sites_m, dfeed_gsm_carrier_m, dfeed_gsm_relation_m, dfeed_umts_carrier_m, dfeed_umts_relation_m,hua_gsm_cme_g2g_m, hua_umts_intra_cme_m, hua_umts_inter_freq_m

#Method that call all the methods which in the class
def call_all(obj, *args, **kwargs):
    for name in dir(obj):
        attribute = getattr(obj, name)
        if ismethod(attribute):
            attribute(*args, **kwargs)


call_all(convert_to_csv.push_all_to_csv())
all_sites_m.push_all_stes_sql()
dfeed_gsm_carrier_m.push_dfeed_gsm_carrier_sql()
dfeed_gsm_relation_m.push_dfeed_gsm_relation_sql()
dfeed_umts_carrier_m.push_dfeed_umts_carrier_sql()
dfeed_umts_relation_m.push_dfeed_umts_relation_sql()
hua_gsm_cme_g2g_m.push_hua_gsm_cme_g2g_relation_sql()
hua_umts_intra_cme_m.push_hua_umts_cme_intra_freq_relation_sql()
hua_umts_inter_freq_m.push_hua_umts_cme_inter_freq_relation_sql()
```

So is there's a faster way to execute multiple `methods` simultaneously?

I hope someone give me good advice

Comment: When you say better, do you mean easier to read, faster? What's the goal?

Comment: @AlexW actually yes because I am doing a script something like import excels in database and create DDL, DML, and DQL as to update the database and then export from a database a multiple excels file this process take too much time about an hour, I hope you could help me :)

Comment: @AlexW beside these I created some pandas function and I am working on different types of inputs like `txt`, `csv`, `xlsx` , and `xlsm` files with a huge data

Comment: @AlexW as the goal from this I am  using this with a GUI `Dash Plotly` Frame workout